# Reset shared_ptr in custom destructor of parent object

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, destructor, smart-pointers

Say I have an object A who'se destructor I need to override for some reason

```
class A 
{ 
private: 
    shared_ptr<B> m_ptr; 
public: 
    A(shared_ptr<B> ptr) {m_ptr = ptr}
    ~A() {m_ptr.reset() // is this needed?
}
```

Do I need to reset the shared_ptr it holds because if I was using the default destructor, it would have called the shared_ptr's destructor inside of it?

Comment: [RAII is your friend.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The pointer cleanup is provided by the destructor of the shared pointer, which is called automatically.

See the relevant entry in isocpp faq: [When I write a destructor, do I need to explicitly call the destructors for my member objects?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#calling-member-dtors)